# How to slice a 1-dimensional ndarray of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, tuples, slice, numpy-slicing

Give a 1-dimensional numpy ndarray as seen in the image below:
[image]

The shape is: `(9,)`
The class type is: `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

How do I slice this data structure so as to get the 3rd and 4th columns (using the term columns loosely) as seen in this image:

[image]

Note that I could have used a conversion to `pandas` dataframe to handle this but my core question is ***how can I slice this using numpy or any inbuilt python slicing function?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to convert array of tuples to array of arrays then use `numpy` slice:

```py
arr = np.array([np.array(list(x))  for x in arr])
arr[:,2:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
sliced = [l[2:4] for l in my_list]
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: IndexError x: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed